# post formdata via ajax to webapi

Tags: c#, ajax, razor, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking to post formdata to a c# web api and have the model binding work.  This looks like it should be possible, but my object is never populated.  I want to keep the code simple and flexible.  ie. i dont want to add a new json attribute to my ajax call every time i add a new form field and i would like to pass files if i wish to (not expecting files to bind to the model).

Here is basically what I have at the moment.

```
$('.save').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/plant/insert',
        data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.processing({ content: 'Saving Plant' });
        },
        error: function () {
            $.error({ content: 'An error occurred saving the plant' });
        },
        success: function (data) {
            location.assign('PlantEdit.cshtml?plant_id=' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

and in my controller

```
public int Insert([FromBody] Plant plant)
{
    return plant.Insert();
}
```

and my model

```
public class Plant : Data
{
    public int plant_id { get; set; }
    public bool live { get; set; }
    public string genus { get; set; }
    public string species { get; set; }
    public string variety_name { get; set; }

    public Plant() { }
}
```

and sample post data

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryc6x6E9JewE0ln4ql
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="live"

on
------WebKitFormBoundaryc6x6E9JewE0ln4ql
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="genus"

test genus name
------WebKitFormBoundaryc6x6E9JewE0ln4ql
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="species"

test species name
------WebKitFormBoundaryc6x6E9JewE0ln4ql
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="variety_name"

test variety name
------WebKitFormBoundaryc6x6E9JewE0ln4ql--
```

The result is the plant instance is not null, but all attributes are null, hence an empty row inserted into the database.  So am I asking for too much, or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what your Plant object looks like. Also, if you look in the developer tools in your browser, what is it posting to the server?

Comment: no worries, ive included some extra information

Answer (score 0):

I would use fiddler to test the post to the service URL, but the data you are posting should be in json format I'm pretty sure:

```
{ plant_id: 1, live: true, genius: "test genius", ... }
```

What is the output of `new FormData($('form')[0])` that it's sending as the POST data?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery#answer-8244082), I believe you would need to do something like this:

```
$('.save').click(function () {
    var fd = new FormData();    
    fd.append( 'name', $('form')[0] );

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/plant/insert',
        data: fd,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.processing({ content: 'Saving Plant' });
        },
        error: function () {
            $.error({ content: 'An error occurred saving the plant' });
        },
        success: function (data) {
            location.assign('PlantEdit.cshtml?plant_id=' + data);
        }
    });
});
```